# Angular: Can I do css on alert and confirm function?

Tags: css, angular

I want to do css on them the problem is they are inside a function and I do not know how I access them.

for example:

```
updateUser() {
      this.usersService.UpdateUser(this.user.id, this.user)
      .subscribe(() => {
          alert("Password changed! You are taken to the login page")
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        },(e)=> {
          this.errors = [];
          if (e.error.errors.Password) {
            this.errors.push(e.error.errors.Password);
          } 
        }
      )
    }
```

Here in the function I want to do css on the alert I have:

```
alert("Password changed! You are taken to the login page")
```

also confirm:

```
  deleteUser(id:string,user:User){
    if(confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete user ${user.userName}`)){
      this.usersService.DeleteUser(id)
      .subscribe(
        () =>{
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

Here in the function I want to do css on the confirm I have:

```
   if(confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete user ${user.userName}`)){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to style an `alert()` or `confirm()`.

That's an HTML Code

```
<div style="position:absolute; width: 200xp; height:50px;background-color:white; border-radius:10p;padding:10px;"><button onclick="TheFunctionAfterConfirm()">Confirm</button>
<button onclick="TheFunctionAfterDisagree()">Disagree</button><div>
```

An alternate way could be to use a library like sweetalert2 (https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples).

If there are problems, add an import to your main script.

Comment: Do they have a replacement?

Comment: You can try this library: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: Is this a directory I need to download?
If so what is her command?

Comment: That's the code: npm i sweetalert2

Comment: GitHub: git clone https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2

Comment: I downloaded the library and it does not allow me to use Swal.fire

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer with an new HTML-Code. This one, you can copy and style. When you create functions for the two buttons, the it works like an confirm.

Comment: I was able to use SWAL I had to add Import, thanks
Add that to the answer and I will mark

Comment: Thanks. That's my first marked answer :-)

Comment: You helped me a lot I did not find it the internet